# filtering index in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently have a dataframe with the index "2018-01-02" to "2020-12-31".
I need to write a program that takes in this dataframe and outputs a new dataframe that contains the first date available for each month.
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: `df.loc[pd.date_range("2018-01-02", "2020-12-31", freq='MS')]` Helpful documentation - [offset aliases](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases), [pd.date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html), [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

Comment: What do you mean by "first date available for each month"?

Comment: @user17242583 For example, there are certain months that are missing the first couple of days. For example, the first of January might be 01-02, and the first day of February might be 02-04 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the source DataFrame is:

```
            Amount
Date              
2018-01-02      10
2018-01-03      11
2018-01-04      12
2018-02-03      13
2018-02-04      14
2018-02-05      15
2018-03-07      16
2018-03-09      17
2018-04-10      18
2018-04-12      19
```

(its index is of *DatetimeIndex* type, not *string*).

If you want **only** the first date in each month, you can run:

```
result = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='MS')).apply(lambda grp: grp.index.min())
```

The result is a Series containing:

```
Date
2018-01-01   2018-01-02
2018-02-01   2018-02-03
2018-03-01   2018-03-07
2018-04-01   2018-04-10
Freq: MS, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

The left column is the index - starting date of each month.

The right column is the value found - the first date in each month from
the source DataFrame.

But if you want **full** first rows from each month, you can run:

```
result = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='MS')).head(1)
```

This time the result is:

```
            Amount
Date              
2018-01-02      10
2018-02-03      13
2018-03-07      16
2018-04-10      18
```

Note that `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='MS')).first()` is a wrong
choice, since it returns in the key the first day of each month,
not the first **existing** day in this month (try it on your own).